# How to create Non-optional stored properties for UIViewController Custom Subclass

Tags: swift, option-type

When subclassing `UIViewController` ( and other similar classes ) we do not have to deal with any initialization, so if I create a stored property that is not an optional, Xcode will complain that there are no initializer.

**So how can I create a non-optional store property in these classes? or should I?**

Comment: Just use the `!` (e.g. `var myProp:MyClass!`) which will auto-unwrap or initialize with a dummy. (I don't like that concept in Swift)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have 2 options:

- initialize it inline

  ```
  var myProp = MyClass()
  ```
- declare it as implicitly unwrapped optional:

  ```
  var myProp: MyClass!
  ```

  and initialize it anywhere in the view controller - usually in `viewDidLoad`. This is the pattern commonly used for outlets, and one of the few cases where I tolerate implicitly unwrapped

Answer (score 3):

Define the property with `lazy`.

```
lazy var myFoo : Foo = Foo()
```

or, if you need to do some stuff to setup `myFoo`:

```
lazy var myFoo : Foo = {
  // Code to create myFoo
  let foo = Foo(...)
  // modify foo if you need to
  return foo
}()     // <== this is a function call; returns the configured `myFoo`
```

As a lazy var, `myFoo` will get assigned to its initial value when it is used for the first time.